# P Key not working after install 19.04

Tags: keyboard, 19.04

I recently made a fresh install of Ubuntu 19.04 on my main comPuter. Now it will randomly ignore the P key unless I make it uPPercase with shift or caPs lock.
The "Del" key is also ignored. I tested the keyboard on another machine with no Problem at all.
Any helP would be really aPPreciated as it is a silly issue but quite annoying.